# Axios headers authorization bearer is missing on callback

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, axios, bearer-token

I am working currently with `Javascript` and `Axios`, on a client side application.
I run an axios request (`refreshToken();`) with an other `axios` request callback (`userAuth();`), in the response of the first `axios` request I receive a new Token.
I try to set this new Token in the headers `authorization` bearer of my callback.
This doesn't work : On the callback (`userAuth();`) the new token is not set, and there is no more Authorization Bearer set in the headers.

When `userAuth();` is not a callback, the `Authorization` `Bearer` is set correctly.
When `userAuth();` is a callback, the `Authorization` `Bearer` is not set.

```
let now = new Date();
let time = now.getTime();
time += 3600 * 1000;
now.setTime(time);

const setTokenOnCookie = (token) => {
    document.cookie = 'token=' + token + '; expires=' + now.toUTCString();
}

const setRefreshOnCookie = (refresh_token) => {
    document.cookie = 'refresh_token=' + refresh_token;
}

const TOKEN_USER = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)token\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
const REFRESH_TOKEN = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)refresh_token\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");

const refreshToken = (userAuthCallback, userUnauthCallback) => {
    axios.post(`${API_URL}/my/url/to/refresh/token`,
        'refresh_token='+REFRESH_TOKEN,
        {headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}
    ).then(res => {
        Promise.all([setTokenOnCookie(res.data.token), setRefreshOnCookie(res.data.refresh_token)])
    .then(()=>{
         userAuthCallback(res.data.token);
     }).catch(err => {
         userUnauthCallback();
     })
}

const userAuth = (token) => {
    if(!token){
        token = TOKEN_USER
    }
    axios.get(`${API_URL}/my/url/to/get/my/user`,
        {headers:{'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`}}
    ).then(res => {
        pushToApplicationPath();
    }).catch(err => {
        catchMyError();
    })
}

const userUnauth = () => {
    document.cookie = 'token=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
    document.cookie = 'refresh_token=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
    document.cookie = 'username=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
    pushToLoginPath();
}

refreshToken(userAuth, userUnauth);
```

Do you know where the problem is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the open issue on GitHub.

[GitHub issue 891](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/891)